# graphic driver installions in HP pavilion g6 2236tx

Tags: 13.04

I have brought a new HP pavilion g6 2236tx lappy, it is radeon HD 7370/7000 2GB graphics card with  & using ubuntu 13.04 simultaneously.

I have installed abacus software in ubuntu 13.04. It was working but the application look like blurry, so I tried to install graphic drivers and from then on wards the launch bar and menu bar is missing, but the application is running fine with the installation of graphic drivers.

Can any one tell me how to find and install the correct graphic drivers and also do not affect the launch bar?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in your Terminal:

> sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates